# New To The GD library. Dynamic text on image resizing

Tags: php, gd

Ok straight to the point. I have a new project I'm working on and I have never had the chance to work with GD before. I have worked with PHP for around 3 years so I'm not new to it just never had a reason until now to explore these features.

So my code is:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
$string = $_POST['userinput'];;

$im = imagecreatefrompng("images/tshirt.png");
$x = 175;
$y = 240;

$font = 'arial.ttf';
$backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255);   //white background
$textColor = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0, 0);   //black text
imagettftext($im, 32, 0, $x, $y, $textColor, $font, $string);
imagepng ($im); 
imagedestroy($im);


?>
```

Now I know $x and $ y are what control the coordinates, but I need the code to be able to resize and center depending on what someone types in. There is a limit of 15 characters that will be placed on this. The application is for a custom tshirt website. I appreciate any help.

I have tried a few things already to no avail so I'm hoping someone can shed some light on what I'm not seeing.

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: watch [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393319/resize-images-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`imagettfbox()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) to do calculate the size of the resulting text. That'll let you do the centering calculations to generate coordinates for the actual text drawing you do with imagettftext().