# How to server-side resize images in PHP5 without external libraries?

Tags: php

**Background**: For an university project I have to use PHP5 to create a web application that also deals with images. I'm not allowed to use any external APIs, frameworks or AJAX.

Is there a native function to resize images in PHP5?

(I know a can specify both width and height for an img tag, but that resizing is done on the client. I'd rather save downsized images on the server.)

Comment: You can use GD if it's enabled in your PHP configuration. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393319/resize-images-with-php

Comment: PHP has no native image manipulation functions. For that you need GD or Imagick, which are external libraries but generally available in most standard PHP installs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GD library has been bundled with PHP since 4.3, and will do what you want: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php. You'll probably want something like [`imagecopyresampled`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php).

Answer (score 2):

Most PHP installations come bundled with the [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php). In fact, I've yet to come across a PHP installation that *doesn't* have GD bundled.

Comment: I have had to uncomment it once or twice in the php.ini, so that may be necessary.